# Encryption in mnesia

Tags: encryption, erlang, ejabberd

How to encrypt mnesia database and what is most secure way to encrypt mnesia database.

Is there any inbuilt method in erlang to encrypt and decrypt the data with high level of security ?

Comment: Could you elaborate a little? There are of course ways to encrypt and decrypt data in Erlang, but this questions is vague and will be hard to answer.

Comment: Maybe you should take a look at crypto lib http://erlang.org/doc/man/crypto.html

Comment: have a look at the whitepaper of zerodb, you can use similar approach on top of mnesia at the query level

Answer (score 5):

**Short answer**

No.

**Long answer**

Database encryption is not a simple subject.

You must first decide what you mean by "encrypted database". Does this mean the data is unreadable in memory? That it is unreadable on disk? Is it externally opaque blobs which are unqueryable aside from a (potentially contextless/meaningless) single key? Is everything one-way? Is the only requirement to compare hashes at high speed? If reversible, how is the key accessed? Is the encryption performed in the database, or is the db only storing things? etc...

In Mnesia (and any other DB) values must be readable to be used in queries. In heavy duty DBs like Postgres having an encrypted DB column means the data is encrypted on the disk, and other things about Postgres mean that you can never know how much of any given table is in memory at one time -- which means disk data must be decrypted and encrypted on the fly every time a row not already cached in memory is traversed. Performance times are *heavily* impacted by this.

Mnesia (and ETS tables, for that matter) can be made to keep all the active data in memory at once -- and to query any of it the data would have to be unencrypted while in memory. Because you can set clear criteria for saving to disk, it would be rather trivial to wrap the disk writing procedure in a call to an encryption library, thus leaving it encrypted on disk, but plaintext (and therefore useful) in memory.

What you do with the keys, on the other hand, is another issue...

Most of the time when we are discussing database encryption what we really mean is whether there is a way to store user passwords as hashes instead of as plaintext (as opposed to storing every value in the entire data store that way). This is a very different issue because for passwords to be useful they need only be comparable, and that does not require retention of the original password at all. (For example, consider [the short set of functions used here](https://github.com/zxq9/erlmud/blob/master/erlmud-0.1/accman.erl#L7-L33) to accept, salt, encrypt and verify passwords.)

The meaning of "encrypted database" requires clarification before any data system can be said to provide an encryption feature, and there are always tradeoffs.